# ios7 data fetch from my server in background mode for every one hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, voip

I'm developing an iPhone app which is to make a phone call from my app using VOIP. For that I have to connect with my server every one hour to register my device and make it available for incoming calls at any time. But in iOS7 How is it possible to connect with my server for every one hour even if it is in background mode. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks,
Jirune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is specific information in the [iOS App programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW47) on implementing a VoIP app -

> To configure a VoIP app, you must do the following:
>
> - Enable support for Voice over IP from the Background modes section of
>     the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this
>     support by including the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the voip value in
>     your app’s Info.plist file.)
> - Configure one of the app’s sockets for
>     VoIP usage.
> - Before moving to the background, call the
>     `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:` method to install a handler to be
>     executed periodically. Your app can use this handler to maintain its
>     service connection.
> - Configure your audio session to handle transitions
>     to and from active use.

Once your socket is configured for VoIP usage, iOS will manage it for you in the background, keeping it alive and notifying your app when there is traffic